# Lock cells after userform input

Tags: excel, vba, user-controls, userform, commandbutton

I need that after a userform is submited that row and cells are locked.

When you insert data in userform those data go to tab called "table". I need tab TABLE to be locked and to allow only userform input.

I need rows and cells from A4 to AF4 onwards to be locked for editing.

I tried with this code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Intersect(Range("A1:D100"), Target)
If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect password:="hello"
    MyRange.Locked = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Protect password:="hello"
End If
End Sub
```

This is how my command button looks

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
Set sh = Sheets("Details")lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
sh.Range("A" & lastRow).value = TextBox3.value
sh.Range("B" & lastRow).value = TextBox4.Text
sh.Range("C" & lastRow).value = TextBox5.Text
Unload Me
End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, manually lock the cells from `A4:AF[ChooseTheLastRow]` and then protect the worksheet with a password and do not allow the selecting of locked cells.

Then in your code do this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Set sh = Sheets("Details") 'you called this TABLE in your text above, no?

  With sh

      .unprotect "PASSWORD"

      Dim lastRow As Long
      lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

      .Range("A" & lastRow).value = TextBox3.value
      .Range("B" & lastRow).value = TextBox4.Text
      .Range("C" & lastRow).value = TextBox5.Text

      .protect "PASSWORD"

  End With

End sub
```